# How to set values in setRepeating method of AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am working on an application in which I have to schedule some events. Events can occur ihn the following order.

- Once only
- Daily
- Monthly
- Yearly

I am using `AlarmManager` to serve the purpose, but I am having confusion regarding `setRepeating` method of `AlarmManager`. What I am inputting is `time of schedule` in `long` and it includes year, month date and time as well. How would I be using the time to schedule the events as I have listed? I mean I am confused regarding how will I set the parameters of time for repeating an event after a defined time where my time includes year as well? Any help regarding this appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

look at the below code

```
private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 10;
AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, YOURStartServiceReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// Fetch every 10 seconds
// InexactRepeating allows Android to optimise the energy consumption
service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
// if you dont need InexactRepeating , use this 
//service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
```

(1000 * 10) can be changed to the intervals you want

Hope it helps!

Comment: how would i get Repeat_Time in milis for Year and Month?

Comment: REPEAT_TIME = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY; // for a day, u can calculate for year and month with this. read here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setNotification() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getData();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    long when =0; 
    intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("eventName", eventName);
    intent.putExtra("eventDescription",eventDescription);

    // Get the AlarmManager service
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Setting_rgRepeatMode);
    selectedRadio=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    long repeatTime=0;
    if(selectedRadio.getText().toString().equals("None"))
    {
        cal.set(mYear,mMonth,mDay,mHour,mMinute,0);
        intent.putExtra("Flag",true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        when=cal.getTimeInMillis();
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,when, pendingIntent);
        return;
    }
    else if(selectedRadio.getText().toString().equals("Daily"))
    {
        intent.putExtra("Flag",true);
        repeatTime=(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY);
    }
    else if(selectedRadio.getText().toString().equals("Weekly"))
    {
        intent.putExtra("Flag",true);
        repeatTime=(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7);
    }
    else if(selectedRadio.getText().toString().equals("Monthly"))
    {
        intent.putExtra("month",mDay);
        repeatTime=(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY);
    }
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,mHour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,mMinute);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    when=cal.getTimeInMillis();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, when,repeatTime, pendingIntent);

}
```

**another class is AlermReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            //              Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            //          String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
            //                  Toast.makeText(context,bundle.getString("eventName"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int icon = R.drawable.event;
            CharSequence notiText = "Event Notification";
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, notiText,time);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Setting.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,intent.getStringExtra("eventName"),intent.getStringExtra("eventDescription"), contentIntent);
            int SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED =  1;
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            Toast.makeText(context,"aavechhe "+intent.getBooleanExtra("Flag",false),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(intent.getIntExtra("month",0)==cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"aavechhe "+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notificationManager.notify(SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED, notification);
            }
            if(intent.getBooleanExtra("Flag",false))
                notificationManager.notify(SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED, notification);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your setting same value of interval for `daily` and `monthly` options. i.e., `repeatTime=(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY);`

Comment: because total days of month are differ. like 29,30,31 it can be any so its better to compare date . now i have check that its monthly or daily repeat.

Comment: and its require less coding for monthly repeat thats why i have done this.